# Nuxt js id through url

Tags: vue.js, parameters, nuxt.js

I want to get ID user, so I have a button DropDown=

```html
<v-menu
  transition="slide-y-transition"
  bottom 
  offset-y
>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }" >
    <v-btn
      color="primary"
      dark
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
    >
      List
    </v-btn>
  </template>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-item
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
      :to="item.url" 
    >
      <v-list-item-title>{{item.title}}</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

and this data:

```html
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
      items: [
      {
        title: 'List User',
        url: '`/user/function/listUser/${route.params.id}`'
      },
      {
        title: 'structure User',
        url: '`/user/function/structUser/${route.params.id}`'
      }      
    ]
  })
}
</script>
```

My intention is to send user ID. This way, I can get with `route.params.id` actually

```js
url: '`/user/function/structUser/${route.params.id}`'
```

is not working, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this one

```js
`/user/function/structUser/${this.$route.params.id}`
```

Also, maybe try this one in a `computed` because it may not be computed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Template strings use backticks only, but yours are using both single quotes and backticks.
2. The substitution value (`route.params.id`) refers to a `route` variable that appears to be undefined in your example. I believe you're trying to access `this.$route`, so the actual substitution should be `this.$route.params.id`

The `items` array should look like this:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          title: 'List User',
          url: `/user/function/listUser/${this.$route.params.id}`
        },
        {
          title: 'structure User',
          url: `/user/function/structUser/${this.$route.params.id}`
        }    
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-template-strings?file=pages%2Fuser%2F_id.vue)